# Dll Type is not loading in execution context , it's loading only in reflection only context

Tags: dynamic, reflection, executioncontext, assembly.reflectiononly

I have a internal project's binaries. And I am trying to load them and use the methods in them through reflection in another project whenever needed.

But the type I am looking for comes as null in execution context . But whereas when I try to load the same type from reflection only context , its returning proper Type .

Because of this I am not able to execute any methods inside the Dll.

Execution context code:

```
 public Type GetTypeFromDll(string dllPath, string typeName)
  {
     var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
     var result = assembly.GetType(typeName);
  }
```

ReflectionOnly context:

```
           try
                {
                    Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(assemblyName.FullName);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(dllPath), assemblyName.Name + ".dll"));
                }

Note: This happens with only one of the types in that dll but the other types seems to be loading fine. But when I check the code , these types are almost similar. Not sure what's missing.
```